# How to simplify $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

This is the original problem:
$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1} = x$.

I'm really confused about how to solve this problem, I come as far as saying this: $\sqrt[4]{5} + \sqrt{1}\cdot \sqrt[4]{5}-\sqrt{1}$.

Comment: Um, no, $\sqrt{a+b}\neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: Try squaring both sides of your original problem and expanding the LHS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: Start with $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+1) \cdot (\sqrt{5}-1)}$, and then use the difference of squares identity, i.e. $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)}$$ $$=\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}-1}$$ $$=\sqrt{5-1}$$ $$=\sqrt{4}$$ $$=2$$

Comment: There is no $-$ in the final answer.

Comment: @Kim Jong Un good point!